# Can I add script to SignUP & SignIn combined?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I tried add custom fields into SUSI via Javascript, but won't work...  If I remove AllowExecution tag on SUSI XML it works...

Error raised on chrome dev tools:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ctpocb2cgol.blob.core.windows.net/CTB2CPOCGOL.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_Social_SUSI/client/perftrace?tx=StateProperties=eyJUSUQiOiJmMjQzMmJiNi0zODlhLTQ1NzMtODhhZC05NDhhYTk5YjI1YmYifQ&p=B2C_1A_Social_SUSI' from origin 'https://ctb2cpocgol.b2clogin.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
unified?local=signup&csrf_token=Wmo4aEx6OVpMNFJ4TTlhZjdJKzd3RVRpUjViOEZ3ZDEzdzZaN2VjYTNyRm1RVXh5N3ArZHkvNkJubFVaM2Jod2N5U3BzOEQyYys5TEpYazA5Um5PSGc9PTsyMDIwLTA5LTEwVDEyOjUxOjU4LjQyNzA2OTZaO2d1azJoUlVJRm9qMTV1bEhaUzQ0NHc9PTt7Ik9yY2hlc3RyYXRpb25TdGVwIjoxfQ==&tx=StateProperties=eyJUSUQiOiJmMjQzMmJiNi0zODlhLTQ1NzMtODhhZC05NDhhYTk5YjI1YmYifQ&p=B2C_1A_Social_SUSI:202 

POST https://ctpocb2cgol.blob.core.windows.net/CTB2CPOCGOL.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_Social_SUSI/client/perftrace?tx=StateProperties=eyJUSUQiOiJmMjQzMmJiNi0zODlhLTQ1NzMtODhhZC05NDhhYTk5YjI1YmYifQ&p=B2C_1A_Social_SUSI net::ERR_FAILED
```

[SignIn screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wRO1.png)

Comment: From the error it seems like you used the customized page and the page is present in Blob.
Please follow this link to enable CORS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-customize-ui

Comment: I fixed, but login page won't work yet

Comment: When i click on Submit button, it don't process and don't proceed to enter too

Comment: If the page didn't redirected then you must have got some error in the Console.

Comment: No, i'dont have more errors on console, in general filters

Comment: More effective if you share screenshots in the question.

Comment: I've added the screen of the console, have nothing...

Comment: Hi @ReniDantas Are you still looking for any help on this?

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity could you explain me about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036476/can-i-recognize-know-what-the-orchestrationstep-im?noredirect=1#comment113237908_64036476

Comment: Sure. Can we consider this issue has been resolved for you