# Can I recognize/know what the OrchestrationStep I'm?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

For example...

I've tried this in InputClaims

```
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Step" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="SelfAsserted-Social-Step01" />
```

And that in OutputClaims

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Step" />
```

So capture all in Javascript (Client-side) in page in this way:

```
var stepPage = $("#Step").text();

switch (stepPage) {
    case "OS-SignIn":
        do_this();
}
```

Worked for me purpose, but it looks a workaround...

Finally, my question is: How I achieve this behaviour in a sophisticated way, like a var in javascript created by B2C or something like that? More native...

Comment: Why are you looking to do this? What’s the overall goal?

Comment: Create elements or customize something in each Step, like change Text, create modal or create another element that doesn't exist in B2C datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

For this use case, you can use a different content definition id for each technical profile.
And then define a matching content definition with matching id, with the respective HTML dataURI for that specific technical profile.

This way you don't need to determine on the front end what orchestrations step is being rendered, as you'll have a HTML specific for each orchestration step.

See below how i create api.page1 as a content definition for this technical profile. Repeat that pattern for each technical profile. Then each page will reference a unique HTML file.

```xml
    <ContentDefinition Id="api.page1">
      <LoadUri>https://your-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/your-container/customize-ui-page1.html</LoadUri>
      <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
      <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.0.0</DataUri>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
      </Metadata>
    </ContentDefinition>
```

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.page1</Item>
```